# GCC shared_ptr Template Error

Tags: c++, templates, g++, shared-ptr

The following function

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<typename T> Tail(const std::shared_ptr<typename T>& cont, size_t n)
{
   const auto size(std::min<size_t>(n, cont->size()));
   return std::shared_ptr<typename T>(new T(cont->end() - size, cont->end()));
}
```

Produces the following error on gcc 4.7.2.

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x
test.cpp:4:27: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:4:66: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp: In function ‘int Tail(const int&, size_t)’:
test.cpp:6:42: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
test.cpp:7:35: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:7:47: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
test.cpp:7:67: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
```

I understand that cont does not 'look' like a pointer, but this compiles fine on VS2012.
How can I write the function for gcc?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove those extra `typename`s

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> Tail(const std::shared_ptr< T>& cont, size_t n)
{
   const auto size(std::min<size_t>(n, cont->size()));
   return std::shared_ptr< T>(new T(cont->end() - size, cont->end()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why is that?

Comment: Simply you don't need them

Answer (score 2):

You are overusing the `typename` keyword. The code should look as follows:

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> Tail(const std::shared_ptr<T>& cont, size_t n)
{
   const auto size(std::min<size_t>(n, cont->size()));
   return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(cont->end() - size, cont->end()));
}
```

For further discussion, see [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to rewrite `typename` before every use of arguments, so please change it to:

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<typename T> Tail(const std::shared_ptr<T>& cont, size_t n)
{
   const auto size(std::min<size_t>(n, cont->size()));
   return std::shared_ptr<typename T>(new T(cont->end() - size, cont->end()));
}
```

this is the same issue as with i.e. classes, you don't write `void myfunc(class MyClass &m){}` but simply `void myfunc(MyClass &m){}`